# How to output an array as a string?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to output an array as a string but i am getting undefined.

The array is  `[1,2,3]` and i want to output the string "123" and add one.

This is what i´ve been trying:

```js
var plusOne = function(digits) {
  number = digits.toString().replace(",","").trim()+1
  console.log(number)
};

plusOne([1,2,3]);
```

Comment: You'll need to convert to number before `+ 1`. Consider using `join()`: `+digits.join('') + 1`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join

Comment: *"but i am getting undefined"* - When I convert your code into a runnable code snippet, that's not the output I see.  Can you update/clarify the code/question?

Comment: Honestly, I haven't worked out if you want to create `"123"` and add `1` to that (to give `"124"` or `124`) or if you want to add 1 to each number of the Array (to give `["11", "21","31"]` or even `["2", "3", "4"]`) or something entirely different. It's possible I'm just tired, but could you show the precise result you're looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this, and I you can add `1` as string or as number as you wish.

```js
function plusOne(digits){
    str='';
    digits.forEach((key)=>{
          console.log(key);
          str+=key.toString();
    })
    console.log(str)
}
plusOne([1,2,3]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to join all elements of the array together. So your function would become:

```
var plusOne = function(digits) {
  number = digits.join("")
  console.log(number)
};
```